# Questions on compact space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be compact.

Q1, Does there exist a dense subset $Y$ of $X$ such that the tightness of  $Y$ is countable?

Q2, Does there exist a dense countably compact left-separated subset $Y$ of $X$?

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: [Crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122857). In the future, please wait some time before posting your question in multiple fora, and when you do, provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to see hear from you that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Comment: Okey. I will Rember.

Comment: Some internet research seems to indicate your Q1 is an open problem.  Have fun!